# How can I replace a given character from user in a string?

Tags: android, arrays, string, replace, char

I am new at android, and trying to make a basic word guess game however I can't do replace part

For example the selected word is "home", and its look like ____ (4 character) on the screen. My goal is when the user entered a character for example "h" and click try button, it should be h__ then entered "m" , h_m_ it goes like this but when I entered a characters nothing changes.

Can anyone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView word;
TextView plsenteracharacter;
EditText givenchar;
Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    plsenteracharacter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    givenchar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    dene = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    //Create a dictionary
    final String [] dictionary = {"home"};
    //Create a random number for selecting a random word from dictionary
    final int rnd = (int)(Math.random()*1);
    //Take a character from user
    final String enteredchar = givenchar.getText().toString();

    //Selected a random string
    final String str = dictionary[rnd];
    //Make that string a charArray
    final char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();

    //Creating "_" length of the string
    final char answer[] = new char[str.length()];
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<charArray.length;k++)
    {
        answer[k]='_';
    }
    word.setText(answer, 0, k);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int p;
            for (p=0;p<charArray.length;p++){
                if(enteredchar== String.valueOf(charArray[p])){
                answer[p] = enteredchar.charAt(0);
                word.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
                }
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code inside `onClick()` to following:-

```
int p;
enteredchar = givenchar.getText().toString();
for (p = 0; p < charArray.length; p++) {
     if (enteredchar.equals(String.valueOf(charArray[p]))) {
             answer[p] = enteredchar.charAt(0);
              word.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
     }
}
```

Comment: @ysfcyln Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() or replaceAll() method of String class

eg.

```
myString.replace("a", "b");
myString.replaceAll("a", "b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the following line `enteredchar = givenchar.getText().toString()` into your `onClickListener`, otherwise it will be executed only once, in `onCreate`, before entering any character.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Nigam Patro's answer is exactly that ı want